# Find the modulo of large number

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I need to find  the value of **y%mod** where **mod** is a prime number and y is defined below
                 $y = a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot a_3 \cdot a_4\cdots a_n$

I know the value of $t = \log a_1 +\log a_2+\cdots+\log a_n$.
 How to find the exact value of **y%mod** since y can be very large so i can't simple used $(Math.E^t)$ ?

Comment: you could try doing the mod for all it's factors one at a time if you hit even one that is 0 remainder you know the whole product is.

Comment: Without any further special properties the best you can do is recursively compute the product of the reduced arguments, e.g.  $\ y_1 := \overline{a_1},\,\ y_{k+1} := \overline{(\overline{a_{k+1}}\,{y_k})}\ $ where $\,\overline{x} := x\bmod p.\ \ $

Comment: You can reduce the factors modulo $y$ before you start and reduce sub-products modulo $y$ as you go along.

Comment: @mark Already said above.

Comment: As well as multiplying them one by one you can know each $a_i$ as a power of an equivalence class and their multiplicative inverses.  e.g. if p = 7.  You know 1,2,3,4,5,6, are $1=-6=3^6,3^2 =\frac 14=-5, 3=\frac 15=-4, 3^4=\frac 12=-3,3^5=\frac 13=-2, 3^5=-1$.

Comment: do you know the values of the $a_i$? the help in the comments would only work if you did, and you haven't explicitly stated you do.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $y \equiv k_1 \cdot k_2\cdots k_n \mod{p}$, where $a_i \equiv k_i \mod{p}$.